# Standard Scaler drops accuracy significantly in Scala Spark

Tags: apache-spark, normalization, feature-scaling, scala

I am working on Scala with Spark for a prediction model. I tried both Normalization and Standard Scaling and both of them drops my accuracy significantly.

Without the accuracy is ~90% (on training set), 77% (on testing set)

With Normalizer or Standard Scaler is 19% (on training), 0% (on testing)

I have the feeling that it's not related to the normalization per se, but more like a code bug.

Here is part of the code:

```
val labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("label")
  .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
  .fit(assemblerDF)

val featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setMaxCategories(4) //if column has more than 4 categories, then use it as continious instead
  .fit(assemblerDF)


val labelConverter = new IndexToString()
  .setInputCol("prediction")
  .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
  .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels)

val scaler = new StandardScaler()
  .setInputCol("indexedFeatures")
  .setOutputCol("scaledFeatures")
  .setWithStd(true)
  .setWithMean(false)

val ml = new LogisticRegression()
  .setMaxIter(15)
  .setFeaturesCol("scaledFeatures")
  .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, featureIndexer, scaler, ml, labelConverter))
```

Where then I pass the Pipeline into a CrossValidator. Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: well if your data is not huge, experiment with python there debug is quite easy, and you can also assess your model easily.

Comment: how many target classes do you have? Could 19% be the accuracy of random guess?

Comment: It’s a two class classification model.

Comment: I'm not a spark/scala person, but why do you give `.setWithMean(false)`? For normal scaling, you should scale both meand and variance. Also, getting `0%` accuracy on testing in one of your attempts sounds like a bug, given a binary classification. Additionally, it seems you perform the `labelConverter` on a different column to your actual predictions (`indexedLabel`) - or is some code missing?

Comment: What are your features like? Are some of them high-cardinality categorical variables? Are any of them interval variables in which the frequency of appearance doesn't follow the numerical order?

Comment: Have you tried manually inspecting the DataFrames? A visual inspect might show should odd about the scaled features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @n1k31t4 said in the comments, it's the `.setWithMean(false)` call (should be true).

Moreover, you don't really need the `StandardScaler` at all, since `LogisticRegression` will perform standardization by default (see the `standardization` param).